# Add Active Class to Current Element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently trying to add active class to current element. I've been trying to test it out with the example from [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com), but there's two issues:

1. The filterDiv class for Show All is not shown each time I refresh
   the page.
2. The active class for btn is still on the Show All div even
       though I clicked another div.

How can I solve these two issues?

Link: [W3Schools How to add active class to current element](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_active_element.asp)

Comment: Please show us some code

Comment: check [ask] as well.

Answer (score 2):

Better use [classList property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

```js
var div = document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[0];

div.classList.add("active");
```

```css
.btn {

  color: red;
  
 }
 
 .active {
 
  text-decoration: underline;
 
 }
```

```html
<div class="btn">My Button</div>
```